# Need Idempotence on rounding operation

Tags: java

In Java, I would like 0.101d, 0.109999999d, and 0.11000d to all be functionally equivalent. I have attempted to use BigDecimal and a MathContext with 2 digits of precision and RoundingMode.CEILING to do this, but my unit test shows that 0.11000 rounds to 0.12. I want 0.110000d to Round to 0.11.

```
    private static MathContext targetMathContext = new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);

public static double roundedTarget(double d) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d,targetMathContext);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

JUnit:

```
    double c = 0.445d;
    double s = 0.5d;
    double p = (s-c)/s; // 0.1099999..... in dfp
    double rgpp = roundedTarget(p); // 0.11
    double rgppp = roundedTarget(rgpp); // 0.12
    // operation is not idempotent as f(x) != f(f(x))   :(

    Assert.assertEquals("These values should be equal",rgpp,rgppp);
```

Solution:

```
    public static double roundedTarget(double d) {
        return  BigDecimal.valueOf(d)
                  .setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING)
                  .doubleValue();
    }
```

Comment: `double` doesn't gain arbitrary precision by your desire to round it. `0.2+0.1` does not equal `0.3` (if you're looking at `double`).

Comment: Why use CEILING? Note that the closest double to 0.11 is 0.11000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625, which CEILING must round up to 0.12.

Comment: I want 0.101, 0.10999, and 0.110000 all to round to 0.11, but 0.1101 to round to 0.12.

Comment: @gbegley What do you want to happen to 0.11000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625?

Comment: So how do you make this operation idempotent?

Comment: The simplest way would probably be to use BigDecimal, in which you can have a number that is exactly 0.11, rather than double in which you cannot.

Comment: yes, but not sure how to satisfy my constraints after I've got a big decimal. I want roundedTarget(0.11d) to return 0.11d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reluctant to call this operation idempotent, since the input of your first application of the function would be different than the next (since the result you get would change the value of `x`).

In either event, main issue is that you're using doubles in one spot (and introducing floating-point inaccuracies), and `BigDecimal` in another (if used correctly, is less impacted by those inaccuracies).

The *easiest* thing to do would be to set a scale of 2 decimal places on your doubles, and then round them however you like.  As an example, all of these values satisfy the conditions you mention you want in your comments.

```
BigDecimal firstDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.101).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);
BigDecimal secondDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.10999).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);
BigDecimal thirdDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.110000).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);
BigDecimal fourthDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1101).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);

System.out.println(firstDecimal); // 0.11
System.out.println(secondDecimal); // 0.11
System.out.println(thirdDecimal); // 0.11
System.out.println(fourthDecimal); // 0.12
```

The main takeaway here is:  if you're going to use `BigDecimal`,  **be consistent with it throughout.**  There's no real reason to interlace or interweave working with raw doubles and `BigDecimal`, as it will only lead to headaches like this.

Comment: Assert.assertEquals("These values should be equal", rgpp, roundedTarget(roundedTarget(roundedTarget(rgpp)))); // pass

Comment: You say their is no idempotence here, my understanding of idempotence is that you get the same result when you apply an operation multiple times. [ f(f(x)) = f(x) ] Have I misunderstood this? e.g. roundedTarget(0.1099) = roundedTarget(roundedTarget(0.1099))

Comment: You're likely right. The main reason I didn't feel that it was idempotent was that your input for the first `f(x)` wasn't going to be the same as your second application of `f(x)`.  I can amend the answer.

Comment: I suppose I wasn't clear enough in my title, as idempotence in the rounding operation wasn't really what I was after, but in my method call. I've updated it to, hopefully, be better. I've heard about the horrors about double math through out my coding career, and I'm a little shocked I haven't stumbled onto this  before. Thanks for the help. This closes the last bug on a several month project. :)